# The proper phrase with "adeptus"

Tags: sentence-translation, translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

As far as I know *adeptus* means "the one who achieved something", in participial form. *mēta* means "goal" or "turning point", figuratively.

What is the proper combination of them with the meaning "the one who achieved the goal"? *mētae adeptus*, or maybe *mētam adeptus*? If *mēta* is an irregular word, then maybe another word would fit better with *adeptus* to express the same meaning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since *adeptus, adepta, adeptum* is the perfect participle of the deponent verb *adispiscor, adipisci, adeptus sum,* it can be used with the accusative:

> *metam adeptus*
>
> 'he who has achieved the goal'

*Adeptus, adeptus* is also a fourth-declension verbal noun (supine), and so if used with the genitive it is likely to be misunderstood:

> *metae adeptus*
>
> 'the attainment of the goal'